# ValueError: Layer "model_1" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, valueerror

I am trying to build a text classification model using the Bert pre train model, but I keep getting an error when I try to fit the model.

The error says

```
ValueError: Layer "model_1" expects 2 inputs but it received only 1 input tensor. 
Inputs received: \[\<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 309) dtype=int32\>\]
```

I am also using TensorFlow and other Python libraries.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from data_helpers import load_data
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers import Dropout,Flatten
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report 
from transformers import TFBertModel

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding
# Data Preparation
print("Load data...")
x, y, vocabulary, vocabulary_inv = load_data()
np.save('data1-vocab.npy', vocabulary) 
sequence_length = x.shape[1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

bert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

def create_model(bert_model, max_len=sequence_length):
    
    ##params###
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5, decay=1e-7)
    loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
    accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()


    input_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_len,),dtype='int32')
    
    attention_masks = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_len,),dtype='int32')
    
    embeddings = bert_model([input_ids,attention_masks])[1]
    
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")(embeddings)
    
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = [input_ids,attention_masks], outputs = output)
    
    model.compile(opt, loss=loss, metrics=accuracy)
    
    
    return model


model = create_model(bert_model,sequence_length)
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=32, batch_size=32,verbose=1)
```

I have changed the parameters of .fit() function but nothing works

Comment: Your model takes two inputs, you are passing only one input, so the problem is clear, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Where actually the problem occurs? what mistake did I make in my code? What changes should I make in the code?

Comment: I already told you the problem, we cannot tell you what changes to make, because we have no idea where the second output should come from, you should study the network you are trying to train before using it.

Comment: in second last line ofyour code why are you encasing 2 valiables into 1 list. try removing square brackets and revet if error is solved or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite clear that your code is:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = [input_ids,attention_masks], outputs = output)
```

So the inputs here you need 2 inputs (`input_ids` and `attention_masks`) but in the `fit` function you only pass 1 inputs to the model:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=32, batch_size=32,verbose=1)
```

So you should learn more about the model before you fix that bug. I mean you need to know that what your model expect to and the structure of input or output of your model.